# mysql find by description where description equals to id number without using id colum

Tags: php, mysql, search, find, identity-column

hello first question over here.
I have a query that searchs a column "description" passing the id in where clause, without using the "id" column, how it is possible?

table parameters_companies

id description_parameter value_parameter id_company 
1              BASE UTC                      7                       1  
2          WARRANTY                  10                       1
3           BASE UTC                   15                        2

This doenst work, because description dont have numbers

```
SELECT
value_parameter
FROM
parameters_companies
WHERE
description_parameter = 1 AND
id_company = 1
```

but this works. Why and how this works? it's a good practice to use it?

```
SELECT
parameters_companies.value_parameter
FROM
parameters_companies
WHERE
parameters_companies.description_parameter = 1 AND
parameters_companies.id_company = 1
```

this returns **value_parameter = 7**, and if you change id_company = 2 returns **value_parameter = 15**
so, parameters_companies.description_parameter = 1 search by the "id column" and later search by the column with same "description"?

EDIT:
it's because is defined as a "Enum Column" I didn't notice, i never use that type of column
thx @CaptRespect @Up_One for your time.

Comment: by your logic wouldn't you expect value_parameter = 10 if you changed description_parameter = 2?  What database are you using and how are the columns defined?

Comment: Mysql with php and it's an "enum" column

Answer (score 0):

They will both run without error ,but will return nothing !
**What was your point ?**

```
mysql> create table parameters_companies(
    -> id int,
    ->  description_parameter varchar(20),
    ->  value_parameter int,
    ->  id_company int
    ->  );

insert into parameters_companies values ('1','BASE UTC','7'Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

,mysql>
mysql> insert into parameters_companies values ('1','BASE UTC','7','1');
insert into paraQuery OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

metermysql> insert into parameters_companies values ('2','WARRANTY','10','1');
 intoQuery OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

 pmysql> insert into parameters_companies values ('3','BASE UTC','15','2');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

ct * from parameters_companies;mysql>
mysql> select * from parameters_companies;
+------+-----------------------+-----------------+------------+
| id   | description_parameter | value_parameter | id_company |
+------+-----------------------+-----------------+------------+
|    1 | BASE UTC              |               7 |          1 |
|    2 | WARRANTY              |              10 |          1 |
|    3 | BASE UTC              |              15 |          2 |
+------+-----------------------+-----------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> SELECT
    -> value_parameter
    -> FROM
    -> parameters_companies
    -> WHERE
    -> description_parameter = 1 AND
    -> id_company = 1;

SELEEmpty set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql>
mysql> SELECT
    -> parameters_companies.value_parameter
    -> FROM
    -> parameters_companies
    -> WHERE
    -> parameters_companies.description_parameter = 1 AND
    -> parameters_companies.id_company = 1;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: thx for the answer, I asked a lot and a coworker told me it's because is a enum column